# Differential equation - with $d[xy]$ term

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**Question:**

> Find the general solution of: $$y + \frac{d[xy]}{dx} = x(\sin x+\log x)$$

Not sure how I would begin this problem. Should I simplify $\frac{d[xy]}{dx}$ into terms of $dy$ and $dx$? What should be a general approach for such questions?

Comment: $y$ is a function of $x$. So $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}[xy] = x\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} + y$.

Comment: @rubik Okay. So that would be the first step. I'm unable to solve it further though.

Comment: Multiply by $x$ to get LHS as $(x^2y)'$. Then integrate RHS by parts.

Comment: @A.G. I see. We take advantage of the fact that the left hand side becomes a exact differential equation?

Answer (score 0):

Simplify 
$$d(xy)/dx=dx/dx\cdot y + x \cdot dy/dx$$

You will get

$$2y+x\frac{dy}{dx}=x(\sin(x)+\log(x))$$

Now you have diffrent ways to solve this:

1. Solve homogenous $y_h$(left hand side) 
   $$2y_h+x\frac{dy_h}{dx}=0$$
   and guess praticular solution $y_p$-> hard to guess
2. Solve homogenous $y_h$(left hand side) 
   $$2y_h+x\frac{dy_h}{dx}=0$$
   and calculate particular solution $y_p$ by using variation of constants -> time consuming, but algorithmic
   $$y_p=c(x)\cdot y_h$$
   Plug this into the ODE and solve for $c(x)$.

Your general solution will be
$$y=y_h+y_p$$

Answer (score 0):

May provide some intuition:

$$\frac {d(xy)}{dx} = \frac {d}{dx} (xy) = y+x\frac{dy}{dx}$$